# React component children not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that iterates over an array in its `refs.current` on each render and returns an array of JSX elements that correspond to the `refs.current` array.

I'm treating the array in `refs.current` as a **pseudo-state**. Anyways it works fine usually, but I get this weird case where **it will just not update** the children components.

I even wrote a console log in the return statement, and all the JSX it is spitting back is what should be rendered after the component settles.

```
export type ContextItem = {
  name: string,
  color?: string,
  callback: ContextItemCallback,
  keybind?: string,
  checkbox?: () => boolean,
  refs?: MainContextItemRefs,
  setRefs?: (action: MainContextItemRefsAction, ...args: any) => void,
};
export type ContextItemCallback = (e: React.MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent, refs: WindowRefs,
  setRefs: (action: WindowRefsAction, ...args: any) => void) => void; 

export interface Props {
  windowRefs: WindowRefs;
  setWindowRefs: (action: WindowRefsAction, ...args: any) => void
  menuTitle: string;
}

export interface Refs {
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  items: ContextItem[];
  visible: boolean;
  height: number;
  position: V2 | NodePhysics | DSPhysics;
  offset: V2;
}

export const initRefs: Refs = {
  ref: React.createRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  items: [],
}

export enum RefsAction {
  SET_ITEMS = "SET_ITEMS",
  SET_REFS = "SET_REFS",
}

export const ContextMenu: React.FC<Props> = ({ windowRefs, setWindowRefs, menuTitle }) => {
  let { state: appState, setState: setAppState, refs: appRefs } = React.useContext<AppContextType>(AppContext); //eslint-disable-line

  let {current: refs } = React.useRef({...windowRefs.ui.menus[menuTitle].refs});

  const [ state, setState ] = React.useState(0);

  const reactRender = () => {
    setState(state + 1);
  }

  const setRefs = (action: RefsAction, ...args: any) => {
    if (action === RefsAction.SET_ITEMS) {
      refs.items = [];
      if (windowRefs.interacts.selectAnchor) {
        refs.items = getNodeContextItems(windowRefs, windowRefs.interacts.selectAnchor);
      }
      reactRender();
    } else if (action === RefsAction.SET_REFS && typeof args[0] === "object") {
      for (let objEnt of Object.entries(args[0])) {
        refs[objEnt[0]] = objEnt[1];
      }
      if ("items" in args[0]) {
        reactRender();
      }
    }
  }

  const itemComps: JSX.Element[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < refs.items.length; ++i) {
    itemComps.push(<MainContextItem windowRefs={windowRefs} setWindowRefs={setWindowRefs} mainContextRefs={refs} itemIdx={i} key={i}/>);
  }
  return( //doesnt always return the correct jsx elements
    <div id={menuTitle} className="contextMenu" ref={refs.ref} style={{visibility: "hidden"}}>
      {console.log(itemComps)} // always logs the correct jsx elements
      {itemComps}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Some important notes:

1. Anytime the `refs.items` is updated through the `SET_ITEMS` path, **it sets and renders fine**. Anytime it updates through the `SET_REFS` path is when it sets fine, but **doesn't render correctly**.
2. When it doesn't render correctly, it renders the last `refs.items` array, so setting `refs.items` through `SET_REFS` essentially does nothing.

Comment: It is easier to read the code than to read about the code. Can you show us some code?

Comment: Just added the code, cut out a portion of the component's code that isn't relevant

Comment: Can you try with a unique `key` something other than `index` i.e. `i` in `itemComps.push(<MainContextItem ...  key={i}/>);`?

Comment: No luck. I tried using unique data (name) from each item as the key instead with no difference in outcome.

Comment: Your code looks complex, I tried with a simpler version, and it worked perfectly. Can you reproduce this error in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: I'm starting to think the error is coming from how I'm initializing the components ref. As you can see, I'm indexing an object in another component's ref when I'm initializing the ref. It's ref-ception and it's kinda breaking my brain thinking how these interact on rerenders, so I'm just going to reconstruct the components in a more isolated fashion.